# Bind ng-options to form from a custom directive within a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Showing an example will likely make more sense than trying to explain this. Please reference this http://plnkr.co/edit/ipGYEX?p=preview as it ALMOST does exactly what I need.

In the example, click Add to create a new select menu and choose an option. This should add it to the parent form. Currently I'm handling this aspect with an $emit. The core problem is that I can't find a way to assign $index to each select. I'd like to attach it to the model name in order to make each one unique. However, simply doing something like `ng-model="selectNum{{$index}}` causes an error when passed through `attrs.ngModel`. As is, the ngModel is repeated for each dropdown that's added and thus, every time the form gets overwritten. I WANT to add each select as a unique object to the form - and update that specific instance should the associated select change.

Can anyone provide some insight on how to either attach the $index or perhaps another way of updating the form?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to getting the values into the form object, but here's an option similar to something I'm doing for a very similar situation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/uEHFWgRQ9fP2gpeWuE5y?p=preview

Basically storing the values within the elements of the array being repeated on, then I use that object from the model for a post to the server.

Comment: Good one. That at least let's me save the value.